# Why is collectstatic not copying all my directories?

Tags: python, django, server, collectstatic

Currently working on deployment for my django website. Im trying to get my static files working so obviously I used this command: `python manage.py collectstatic`. Once finished running it prints `119 files copied...` I thought this was working until I cd'd into the newly created `static` directory and didn't find my `css` folder. Weirdly enough, I did see the `admin` folder. Once I saw this, I deleted my `static` folder entirely and attempted to directly copy the static folder using `scp`. I did this and all of my other folders (css, uploads, etc. And also the admin folder) appeared. I tried to `collectstatic` now with all of the folders there only to find out when I do that, it deletes all of my folders except for the `admin` folder. When I start the website up using the runserver command. There is no css on my homepage but there is in the admin page.

This is how everything looks like in the finder.

```
(projectname) ——— env
              ——— excelsite
              ——— pages
              ——— templates
              ——— (settings folder)
              ——— static ——— css, uploads, admin
              ——— manage.py
              ——— db.sqlite3
```

This is my `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/alexholst/excelsite/static"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATICFILES_DIRS = ("/home/alexholst/excelsite/static",)

#STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#    os.path.join('static'),
#    'static',
#)
```

Any help is very much appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure in `settings.py`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

And add your app's static directory there.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: it should, yes ... it just tells Django where to find your files when running `collectstatic`

Comment: you still need to run `collectstatic`, but this time it should collect everything :)

Comment: it says i need something like STATIC_ROOT

Comment: hmmm, when i put static root, it says staticfilesdirs cant have the same code as static root

Comment: If you add your project tree structure to your question, maybe I can be more specific.

Comment: that says that i need static root (if i remove it)

Comment: Here's my conf ... ```STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    # '/var/www/static/',
]```

Comment: and in another project ```STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "my_app", "static"),

    # '/var/www/static/',

]```

Comment: why would '/var/www/static/` be in `STATICFILES_DIRS`? That's not normally where your code repository with static files lives. That's more like a directory to collect the files to (i.e. `STATIC_ROOT`).

Comment: yeah that's why it's commented out